# Run a Script from AutoSys Blob/Glob

Tags: linux, shell, automation, sh, autosys

I want to run a shell script on different machines with an AutoSys CMD job. However, I cannot put the script on each machine.

I tried pushing the script as blob and glob as stdin to `sh` command.

```
...
command: sh
std_in_file: $$blobt
blob_file: /tmp/my_script
...
```

```
...
command: sh
std_in_file: $$globt.my_script
...
```

But this didn't work for some reason. The job fails on force-start and its report says "Unable to fetch STDIN from Application Server". The blob and glob actually exist but become inaccessible in the job.

What to do? Are there any other ways of doing this?